# How do I merge a list of dictionaries by an identical field and sum another field in the process?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, defaultdict

Attempting to merge a list of dictionaries by a url field, which if has an identical dictionary item in the list, will merge the identical ones by this field while adding the sum for another field at the same time.

I've tried using 'setdefault' but it doesn't always work as expected. I'm still getting duplicate results after running the loop.

Here is the list of dicts I'm trying to condense with the sum of the second field added to get its sum where identical urls exist:

```
[
  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-1',
  21,
  'Long Text Field 1',
  'String 1',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg'},
  255],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-1',
  185,
  'Long Text Field 1',
  'String 1',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg'},
  255],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-2',
  296,
  'Long Text Field 2',
  'String 2',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-2.jpg'},
  303],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-3',
  354,
  'Long Text Field 3',
  'String 3',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-3.jpg'},
  388],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-4',
  606,
  'Long Text Field 4',
  'String 4',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-4.jpg'},
  624]
]
```

This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
[
 ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-1',
  206,
  'Long Text Field 1',
  'String 1',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg'},
  255],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-2',
  296,
  'Long Text Field 2',
  'String 2',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-2.jpg'},
  303],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-3',
  354,
  'Long Text Field 3',
  'String 3',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-3.jpg'},
  388],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-4',
  606,
  'Long Text Field 4',
  'String 4',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-4.jpg'},
  624]
]
```

I'm trying

```
for url, long_text, number_to_count, another_field, ..., ... in list:
    d = {}
    d.setdefault(url, {}).setdefault("long text", []).append(long_text)
    d[url].setdefault("number_to_count",[]).append(number_to_count)
    d[url].setdefault("another_field",[]).append(another_field)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can try. It basically groups the sublists from `lst` by the first URL into a defaultdict of lists, then builds a new result only with the second item number summed up.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

lst = ...

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in lst:
    d[item[0]].append(item)

result = [[v[0][0]] + [sum(x[1] for x in v)] + v[0][2:] for v in d.values()]

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[['https://www.website.com/directory/link-1',
  206,
  'Long Text Field 1',
  'String 1',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg'},
  255],
 ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-2',
  296,
  'Long Text Field 2',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-2.jpg'},
  303],
 ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-3',
  354,
  'Long Text Field 3',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-3.jpg'},
  388],
 ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-4',
  606,
  'Long Text Field 4',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-4.jpg'},
  624]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `pandas` you can get something like the following:

```
                                       Page  Count               Text    String                                         Url  Magic
0  https://www.website.com/directory/link-1     21  Long Text Field 1  String 1  https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg    255
1  https://www.website.com/directory/link-1    185  Long Text Field 1  String 1  https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg    255
2  https://www.website.com/directory/link-2    296  Long Text Field 2      None  https://www.website.com/images/image-2.jpg    303
3  https://www.website.com/directory/link-3    354  Long Text Field 3      None  https://www.website.com/images/image-3.jpg    388
4  https://www.website.com/directory/link-4    606  Long Text Field 4      None  https://www.website.com/images/image-4.jpg    624

----

                                       Page  Count  Magic    String                                         Url               Text
0  https://www.website.com/directory/link-1    206    255  String 1  https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg  Long Text Field 1
1  https://www.website.com/directory/link-2    296    303      None  https://www.website.com/images/image-2.jpg  Long Text Field 2
2  https://www.website.com/directory/link-3    354    388      None  https://www.website.com/images/image-3.jpg  Long Text Field 3
3  https://www.website.com/directory/link-4    606    624      None  https://www.website.com/images/image-4.jpg  Long Text Field 4
```

by running the below code.  Note that I had to add dummy values for the missing strings, since your data format is somewhat inconsistent.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-1',
  21,
  'Long Text Field 1',
  'String 1',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg'},
  255],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-1',
  185,
  'Long Text Field 1',
  'String 1',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-1.jpg'},
  255],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-2',
  296,
  'Long Text Field 2',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-2.jpg'},
  303],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-3',
  354,
  'Long Text Field 3',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-3.jpg'},
  388],

  ['https://www.website.com/directory/link-4',
  606,
  'Long Text Field 4',
  {'url': 'https://www.website.com/images/image-4.jpg'},
  624]
]
columns = ['Page', 'Count', 'Text', 'String', 'Url', 'Magic']

for d in data:
    if len(d) != 6:
        d.insert(3, None)
    d[4] = d[4]['url']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)


agg = dict.fromkeys(columns, 'first')
agg.update({'Count': 'sum'})
del agg['Page']
df2 = df.groupby(['Page'], as_index=False).agg(agg)

pd.options.display.width = 0
print df
print '\n----\n'
print df2
```

Comment: That's cool, thank you. You're right, my code is inconsistent, thank you for pointing that out as well. Fixed. I love pandas!